# Missing object in module skimage.color

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have installed scikit-image version 0.15 (through `pip install scikit-image`) yet I am getting a

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rgb2ypbpr'
```

whenever I run this:

```
import skimage
import skimage.color as scc
import scipy.misc

image = scipy.misc.imread("./image.jpg", mode='RGB')
new = scc.rgb2ypbpr(image)
```

Not sure what is wrong as  rgb2ypbpr should be a valid method

Comment: When I get such errors, I look into module code, also into __init__.py of package. Maybe, you'll find answer there

Comment: I faced the same problem. An alternative is `from skimage import color`.